# Android Calendar API - event adding result catch

Tags: android, events, calendar

I'm adding events to the Android calendar using Calendar API, but I'm unable to check if user actually added my event or cancelled it.

I'm firing `startActivityForResult` with event intent and then I'm checking the result with `onActivityResult`, but I always get `resultCode = 0` and `data = null`.

Is there a way to get that data and check what user has actually done?